# %JAVA_HOME% and root certificate JVM import: What's wrong with my path?

Tags: java, jvm, certificate, truststore

I've been trying for the better part of the day now to import a root certificate into a JVM trust store according to this [guide](http://connect2id.com/blog/importing-ca-root-cert-into-jvm-trust-store). I'm currently stuck at the step of actually importing the cert through the command

```
keytool -importcert -alias startssl -keystore %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit -file ca.der
```

It's from the guide, I just modified it from Linux format to Windows format. The task seems simple enough, but I can't get the command line to see the keytool utility. I of course looked around and had a bunch of fun with reinstalling Java, checking Java versions in all different places, and that space in "Program Files" which the command line can't wrap its head around, but the system still won't budge and I'm lost.

Here are my relevant env. variables as they are now:

JAVA_HOME: `C:\%PROGRAMFILES%\Java\jdk1.8.0_112`

PATH: `...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Argument with which the function for adding is called: `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts`

The path in the command should by all rights resolve to 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\security\cacerts`
, and the one in the Path env. variable should likewise end up as 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin`. I have manually checked for the existence of the keytool utility and the correct folder names in all the paths. The error message isn't very helpful, it just says `'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`, so no insights from there except that Windows can't cobble together a path for some reason. I have to use %PROGRAMFILES% because before, here was an error because Windows evaluated the path as something like `Files/foo/bar` What am I still missing? I suspect a typo or a missing slash or something like that. How do I get the import to work properly?

Comment: java home should be `%PROGRAMFILES%\Java\jdk1.8.0_112` not `C:\%PROGRAMFILES%\Java\jdk1.8.0_112` because `%PROGRAMFILES%` is an alias for `C:\Program Files`

Comment: Now it gives the same error as before, the one that pops up because of the space: `Illegal option:  Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\security\cacerts
keytool -importcert [OPTION]...`